# Rack middleware how to redirect to a view in my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rack

In my Rails 3.1 app I created a Rack Middleware to verify access. If access is not approved user is to be redirected to a page. Specifically it will be a page I already have in my views. Suppose I am trying to redirect to dummy.html.erb with I have defined in my routes.rb as

```
match '/dummy', to :'page#dummy'
```

with page being my controller.

I've tried the following but I appear to be stuck in some redirect loop.

My Rack middleware located in /lib :

```
class AccessVerifier
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call (env)
    #....
    #....do some type of verification here and redirect if fail verification
    #....
    [301, {"Location" => '/dummy', "Content-Type" => "text/html"}, []]
  end
end
```

In application.rb I have

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.middleware.use "AccessVerifier"
```

I also tried calling a controller in my middleware but again I am caught in some redirect loop. I called the controller from my middleware class like this:

```
  def call (env)
    ...
    status,headers,response=PageController.action("validateAccess").call(env)
  end
```

and in my controller:

```
 class PageController < ApplicationController
   def validateAccess
     redirect_to :controller => 'page', :action => "dummy"
   end
   ...
 end
```

I've seen redirecting done successfully without the use of Rack Middleware, for example only with controllers, but please note that I need to do this in middleware before my application is run.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is so simple I felt silly. The problem is that when I redirect to somewhere say /dummy that in turns causes another pass through the Rack middleware and goes through my AccessVerifier code all over again which redirects to /dummy and does this over and over again thus causing the redirect loop. To fix it I force a stopping point by checking if the incoming path is included in the list of my stopping points(with /dummy being in that list) then stop. So an example in pseudo code

```
if path in ListOfAcceptableStoppingPoints
    @app.call(env)
```

This fixes the redirect loop issue but now I am questioning if it would be better for my specific case to not use rake middleware as I have found that now I am filtering other things out such as assets. Sure I could try to go through and pick out everything I think I need to allow to go through but this seems too tedious and not correct. It seems like ultimately, I need to do my filtering at the rails level not at the rack level.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have an answer off of the top of my head to directly answer your question.  However, I would suggest using the cancan gem to handle authorization instead of creating a homegrown solution.  See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan